# If the base table underlying a view is restructured, eg. attributes are added, does the application code accessing the view need to be redone?

Tags: sql-server

If the base table underlying a view is restructured, eg. attributes are added, does the application code accessing the view need to be redone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't change any of the columns used by the view then no.

If you change a column used by the view - e.g. rename it - the view can be changed to still return the old column name, in which case you would not need to change the application code.